# angular 2 Retrieving values from check boxes

Tags: angular2-forms

I have two check boxes and they are populating when the user is selected, but I now need to check the values and return them before saving them back to database in case they have been changed, below is my plunker with my working code if you select a tradesman from the drop down the ticket boxes are populated.

If someone could advise how I can get check the tick box values that would be great, this is what I have tried but I am missing something:

```
<input type="input" name="adminis" id="adminis" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tradesman.user_roles"/>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ecQgg4JHU1l1ZaY1CBJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find whether a checkbox value is changed or not, you can use (change) attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="tradesman?.user_roles?.includes('Administrator') ? true : false" value="Administrator" (change)="valueChanged($event)"/>Admin
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="tradesman?.user_roles?.includes('General User') ? true : false" value="General User" (change)="valueChanged($event)" />General
```

In your component, you can manage the data using the event passed.

```
valueChanged(e:any){
  /* e.target.name - for getting the changed field name */
  /* e.target.checked - for getting the value - true(checked)/false(unchecked) */
}
```

Then you can update your array or whatever with this new value.

Comment: Hi Veena,

Thanks that worked perfectly really appreciate you help again.

Would you mind looking at this SO ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909238/angular-2-selecting-option-from-select-list-based-on-passed-in-parameter )for me as the answers I have been given do not seem to work. 

Thanks

Comment: Hi Stephenad, i didnt understand the term 'SO' which you have referred in your last comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Veena, by SO I mean Stack Overflow question and then the link I gave after it :D

Comment: yeah sure, will give it a try